# setRowspan method is not working in iText 2.1.7

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText 2.1.7 version. I am trying to set the rowspan for on of the PdfCell.

Below is the code:

```
PdfCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ABC",fontMethod));
        cell.setRowspan(2);
```

But it says cannot find symbol cell.setRowspan(2);

Answer (score 0):

You assign a `PdfPCell` instance to a `PdfCell` variable. Those types are completely different (look for the center `P`). This cannot work.

If you assigned the `PdfPCell` instance to a `PdfPCell` variable, `setRowspan` should work as it has been introduced in iText 2.1.6, i.e. before your 2.1.7:

```java
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ABC",fontMethod));
cell.setRowspan(2);
```